# How do I cleanly shut down a mesos-slave?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I have a use case where I need to cleanly shut down a mesos-slave and stop all the frameworks that are executing on the node. Using Marathon and Spark and docker as a containerizer, so there are several other docker containers running for the framework tasks on the node, and I would like to stop these when (cleanly) stopping the slave.

Surprisingly, I can't find any documentation covering this. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I'm really surprised that I cannot find official documentation for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sending `SIGUSR1` to the slave process.

As an alternative, you can also simply kill the process and remove slave's working directory, the Mesos Master will forget about this slave and all executors will die after some period of time. However, it's not that "clean" in comparison to the previous approach.

Comment: SIGUSR1 did exactly what I want... shut down mesos-slave and all the tasks underneath.